# SettingWithCopyWarning in pandas when combining assignments

Tags: pandas

I get a strange `SettingWithCopyWarning` warning and have scaled it down to the following example (pandas 0.19.1)

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(index=['a','b'])
data['col1'] = [1, -1]
data['col2'] = [2, 4]
data.col2 = 0.1 * data.col2
data.col1[data.col1 < 0] = 0
```

I don't get the `SettingWithCopyWarning` if I do either the last line or the second to the last line. Either of the following two snippets doesn't raise the warning, but if I do both statements I do get the warning. Does anybody know why? How should I modify the code so that I don't get the warning? I want to use it in a class and I cannot explain the behavior.

```
# this works
data = pd.DataFrame(index=['a','b'])
data['col1'] = [1, -1]
data['col2'] = [2, 4]
data.col2 = 0.1 * data.col2
#data.col1[data.col1 < 0] = 0

# this also works
data = pd.DataFrame(index=['a','b'])
data['col1'] = [1, -1]
data['col2'] = [2, 4]
#data.col2 = 0.1 * data.col2
data.col1[data.col1 < 0] = 0
```

Comment: The last line has chained indexing. Consider changing it to `data.loc[data.col1 < 0, 'col1'] = 0`.

Comment: That does indeed work, but I am not sure the warning is shown here correctly. Especially since the last line can be run if you don't run the second to the last line. But I like the syntax you suggest and it doesn't throw the warning.

Comment: That's probably because if you exclude the line `data.col2 = 0.1 * data.col2`  the datatypes remain unchanged. data.values is a single numpy array of type int64. But when you execute that line you are you might be changing the memory layout because it is converted to float. Now data.col1 might be returning a copy instead of a view because of that. If that's a copy, boolean slice will be a problem.